# SQL syntax issue with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in MySql. Table 1 has the following fields

Table1:

```
EventType
-etid
-description
```

Table 2:

```
EventAsks
-etid
-qid
```

Table 3:

```
Questions
-qid
-textofquestion
```

If I have a specific etid and I want to find all the questions that the event asks for. So given the following tables...

```
EventType
etid     description
1        hiking
2        biking


EventAsks
etid      qid
1         1
1         3
2         2
2         3

Questions
qid   textofquestion
1     Is it fun?
2     Is it lots of exercise
3     Is it expensive
```

So the result of a given etid say etid=1, I would like the questions associated with etid=1 returned...

```
Result
Is it fun?
Is it expensive?
```

I am sure this had to do with a join, but I don't know exactly how to do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried, the one that gives the syntax error, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `eventasks`
WHERE etid =1
INNER JOIN Questions
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Your inner join is invalid as it's not specifying a constraint to show how the join should work; see Madbreaks answer for details how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic *n-to-n* relationship:

```
SELECT Questions.textofquestion FROM EventType
LEFT JOIN EventAsks ON EventAsks.etid = EventType.etid
LEFT JOIN Questions ON Questions.quid = EventAsks.qid
WHERE EventType.etid = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
SELECT Questions.textofquestion
FROM EventType
   INNER JOIN EventAsks 
        ON EventType.etid = EventAsks.etid
   INNER JOIN Questions 
        ON EventAsks.qid = Questions.qid
WHERE EventType.etid = 1
```

Since you already have the `etid=1` yuou can simplify as:

```
SELECT Questions.textofquestion
FROM EventAsks 
   INNER JOIN Questions 
        ON EventAsks.qid = Questions.qid
WHERE EventAsks.etid = 1
```